# git messed up by recursive symlink

Tags: git

I've accidentally created a recursive symlink in the base directory of a git repository, now all my commits look like this:

```
automated commit: modify rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/rir/RADB/myfile;
```

I've removed the symlink already, it doesn't show up there anymore with *git ls-files*, when using *git ls-tree --full-name* the names look correct. I've also tried rolling back to before that symlink got added.

Is there a way to clean up this mess without having to recreate the repository from scratch?

Thanks